# UIMA Ruta - Type "W" not defined in this script/block

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm still learing UIMA Ruta and I'm getting the error "Type "W" not defined in this script/block!" under the two "W" in a project I've found online.

```
WORDLIST ActionList = 'Action.txt';
DECLARE Annotation Action(STRING value);
W{INLIST(ActionList) -> CREATE(Action, "value" = W)};
```

What could be the problem here?
Thanks

Edit: 
The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value for descriptor is missing - Arguments: [descriptor, null, inputFolder, C%3A%2FUsers%2FSergio%2FDesktop%2FUIMA-Ruta-master%2FOstapTest%2Finput, outputFolder, C%3A%2FUsers%2FSergio%2FDesktop%2FUIMA-Ruta-master%2FOstapTest%2Foutput, mode, run, encoding, Cp1252, view, _InitialView, inputRecursive, false, addsdi, false, serialFormat, XMI]
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.throwException(RutaLauncher.java:172)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.parseCmdLineArgs(RutaLauncher.java:111)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:176)
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace or add details how you try to execute the rules? Is this an error message in the Ruta Editor?

Comment: This is the project I'm trying to replicate: https://github.com/ostap-lozinskyi/UIMA-Ruta . Eclipse shows me this error in the file "FirstLevelAnnotations.ruta" when the project is imported.